How to get the applied promo code once the payment is success?
I need to know the promo code applied by the buyer during the checkout. The webhook event "checkout.session.completed" and the retrieve checkout session by id API don't have this detail, they only have a discount applied.
How can I get the applied promo code once the payment is done?

The checkout.session.completed event contains a Checkout Session object but without line_items expanded. What you'll need to do is make a separate call to retrieve the CheckoutSession and expand line_items.data.discounts to get details about the coupon used: https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items-data-discounts

For example, we get times_redeemed for the coupon; how do we get times_redeemed for the promo code in the same response? in response promotion_code value is promo code name, not object. I tried adding line_items.data.discounts.discount.promotion_code as expanded but getting "You cannot expand more than 4 levels of a property. Property: line_items.data.discounts.discount.promotion_code"

Right, looks like this is a known limitation: https://docs.stripe.com/expand#multiple-levels
You'll need to do this in two requests: retrieve the Session and expand line_items.data.discounts, inspect the value of line_items.data.discounts.discount.promotion_code, then retrieve the Promotion Code
